# Styling elements under a given Id

Tags: css

So I have this div called top nav, i.e.:

```
<div id="topnav">
```

And I would like to style all of the `A` elements under this div, however NOT the `A` elements outside of this div.

How would I go about that in CSS?

Comment: do you need any further help with this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#topnav a { /* write here your CSS rules */ }
```

Comment: This selector is not what he's asking for. He wants to style all the <a> elements inside the div. With your selector, only the direct descendants of the div would be styled. For instance, if there is another div with an <a> inside, it would not be styled.

Comment: This is not an answer, it is just code. Without explanations it doesn't contribute enough to the Wiki. Please improve or delete it.

Comment: If you think my contribute isn't enough, you're free to improve my answer instead of just downvote it.

Answer (score 5):

Specify `a` as a descendant of `#topnav` in the selector:

```
#topnav a {
    /* styles */
}
```

See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say a simple `#topnav a` selector would do.

Edit: sorry I misread. I thought you wanted to style all the elements under it, not just the `<a>` elements. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

if you want this to all the elements  inside the div, it must be...

jquery

```
$('#topnav a').css('color', 'red')
```

css

```
#topnav a {
color:red;
}
```

Comment: He's asking to style all the <a> elements, not all the elements. I misread it too initially.